# How to open file/directory Get Info window?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Is there a way to open the Finder's "Get Info" window within my app for some path, programmatically?

[image: Get Info Window]

Comment: Just to be clear: are you asking to switch to Finder and show the actual Info panel, or are you trying to display said panel within your app?

Comment: I want to display panel within my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some applescript and it's quite easy:

```
set macpath to POSIX file "/Users/rross/test.applescript" as alias
tell application "Finder" to open information window of macpath
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it without applescript?) Simply I had never worked with applescript

Comment: Will this display the panel in-app as the OP wants?  I'm not an AppleScript guy, but doesn't this just invoke the panel within Finder?

Comment: @ConradShultz hmm I started my answer before the comments were added on the original post. And, Kira, applescript is quite easy to deal with, do some google searching and you should be able to find out how to execute applescript in your own app.

Answer (score 7):

There is another simple solution, you can see in the apple's "Photo Search" project.

Following is the code which you can use to show "Get Info" Window for single file as per the sample.

```
- (void)infoButtonAction:(NSOutlineView *)sender {
    // Access the row that was clicked on and open that image
    NSInteger row = [sender clickedRow];
    SearchItem *item = [resultsOutlineView itemAtRow:row];
    // Do a "reveal" in finder
    if ([item filePathURL]) {
        NSPasteboard *pboard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithUniqueName];
        [pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSStringPboardType] owner:nil];
        [pboard setString:[[item filePathURL] path]  forType:NSStringPboardType];
        NSPerformService(@"Finder/Show Info", pboard);
    }
}
```

I have further modified the code as per my need to show the dialog for multiple files as follows:

```
NSPasteboard *pboard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithUniqueName];
[pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSStringPboardType] owner:nil];

NSMutableArray *fileList = [NSMutableArray new];

//Add as many as file's path in the fileList array
for(FileItem *item in fileItems) {
    [fileList addObject:[[item.filePath filePathURL] path]];
}

[pboard setPropertyList:fileList forType:NSFilenamesPboardType];
NSPerformService(@"Finder/Show Info", pboard);
```

Hope, this will help, and FYI, this will work with sandboxed App in Lion and later.

Comment: You use the clipboard to store the file ? But when the user hits CMD V would that also paste the file we requested a "Get Info" ?
If so, wouldn't it be good to delete the file out of the Pasteboard after getting the Info (also for memory reasons ?)

Comment: Sure, you can remove the files from clipboard as per your need, after NSPerformService call with some delay.

Answer (score 3):

I used this code for openings one file "Get Info" window

```
NSPasteboard *pboard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithUniqueName];
[pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSStringPboardType] owner:nil];
NSString *path = [selectedDuplicateItem getFileItemPath];
[pboard setString:path forType:NSStringPboardType];
NSPerformService(@"Finder/Show Info", pboard);
```

but, there is some bug. If my file path contains a space, for example `path = @"/Users/alexanderyolkin/Downloads/DETest/Folder/LICENSE 2"`, NSPerformService opens two windows "Get Info" - for path and for the same file without space or for folder.

So, the solution was in using
`[pboard setPropertyList:fileList forType:NSFilenamesPboardType];`

and the code is

```
NSPasteboard *pboard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithUniqueName];
[pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSStringPboardType] owner:nil];

NSString *path = [selectedDuplicateItem getFileItemPath];
NSMutableArray *fileList = [NSMutableArray new];
[fileList insertObject:path atIndex:0];

[pboard setPropertyList:fileList forType:NSFilenamesPboardType];
NSPerformService(@"Finder/Show Info", pboard);
```

thats work perfect

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no API to obtain an info panel for in-app display.  (I welcome correction on this point.)  The closest thing that comes to mind is the [preview panel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Quartz/Reference/QLPreviewPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html) available through the Quick Look APIs.

I think that all the information you would need to construct your own can be obtained via the [NSWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) classes.

Comment: Of course I can make my window, but I do not want to "reinvent the wheel" if this has been done to me

Comment: In this case I think you might have to.  I bet you're not alone - maybe consider posting your result to GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

2022, macos, swift:

open "Get Info" window of finder:

```
func openGetInfoWnd(for url: URL) {
    openGetInfoWnd(for: [url])
}

func openGetInfoWnd(for urls: [URL]) {
    let pBoard = NSPasteboard(name: NSPasteboard.Name(rawValue: "pasteBoard_\(UUID().uuidString )") )
    
    pBoard.writeObjects(urls as [NSPasteboardWriting])
    
    NSPerformService("Finder/Show Info", pBoard);
}
```