# How to get the "get info" pane in finder programmatically (Objective-c)?

Tags: objective-c, metadata, directory, osx-mountain-lion

we right-click a folder or file, and then we can choose "get info" option to show some info.
I wonder whether we can do this through objective-c?

Comment: Jet, I assume you never found a way to do this?

Comment: This works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048060/how-to-open-file-directory-get-info-window